# Php str_replace one by one in loop

Tags: php, replace

I have a string like

**A name Tokyo 26, B name Moscov 45, C name Newyork 26, D name Berlin 67, E name Paris 37, F name London 39**

I want to replace **name** words as name1 name2 name3....
so the final string will be like

**A name1 Tokyo 26, B name2 Moscov 45, C name3 Newyork 26, D name4 Berlin 67, E name5 Paris 37, F name6 London 39**

How can I replace matching words each time with different value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , store it on array and join again

```
$str = 'A name Tokyo 26, B name Moscov 45, C name Newyork 26, D name Berlin 67, E name Paris 37, F name London 39';

$toReplace = 'name';
$count = explode(',',$str);
$array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($count); $i++) {
  $num = $i + 1;
  $array[] = str_replace($toReplace , $toReplace . $num , $count[$i]);
}

$new_str = implode(',',$array);
echo $new_str;
```

Output with :

> A name1 Tokyo 26, B name2 Moscov 45, C name3 Newyork 26, D name4
> Berlin 67, E name5 Paris 37, F name6 London 39

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with an regex

```
$string = 'A name Tokyo 26, B name Moscov 45, C name Newyork 26, D name Berlin 67, E name Paris 37, F name London 39';

$counter = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/name/', function($val) use (&$counter) {
    return $val[0] . ++$counter;
} , $string);
```

> A name1 Tokyo 26, B name2 Moscov 45, C name3 Newyork 26, D name4 Berlin 67, E name5 Paris 37, F name6 London 39